# Cannot confirm upload process firing on Plupload

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, plupload

I've been working a page for plUpload to work with ColdFusion to see how feasible it wouldf be to implement into one of my ColdFusion systems here... Once I'm sure it works I'm planning on using local copies of the JS scripts and CSS. So far, the front end looks great, but I've no way to ascertain why the ColdFusion upload page `upload_files.cfm` is not being called... I've thrown in some CFMAIL tags into the ColdFusion page to be called to ensure I"m getting something running... but alas no emails have arrived... I'd love it if someone can point out what it is I've done wrong here...

I've based the main front-end on an HTML page, called custom.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

<title>Plupload - Custom example</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.plupload.com/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.plupload.com/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.plupload.com/css/my.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.plupload.com/css/prettify.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.plupload.com/css/shCore.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.plupload.com/css/shCoreEclipse.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.plupload.com/plupload/js/jquery.ui.plupload/css/jquery.ui.plupload.css" media="screen" />

<!-- production -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="font: 13px Verdana; background: #eee; color: #333">

<h1>Custom example</h1>

<p>Shows you how to use the core plupload API.</p>

<div id="uploader">
    <p>Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Initialize the widget when the DOM is ready
$(function() {
    $("#uploader").plupload({
        // General settings
        runtimes : 'html5,html4',
        url : "upload_files.cfm",

        // Maximum file size
        max_file_size : '2mb',

        chunk_size: '1mb',

        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize : {
            width : 200, 
            height : 200, 
            quality : 90,
            crop: true // crop to exact dimensions
        },

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters : [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
            {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip,avi"}
        ],

        // Rename files by clicking on their titles
        rename: true,

        // Sort files
        sortable: true,

        // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
        dragdrop: true,

        // Views to activate
        views: {
            list: true,
            thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
            active: 'thumbs'
        },

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url : '/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url : '/plupload/js/Moxie.xap'

    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.plupload.com/js/bootstrap.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.plupload.com/plupload/js/plupload.full.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.plupload.com/plupload/js/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.plupload.com/js/themeswitcher.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

upload_files.cfm, the URL being called, code is below:

```
<!---
The Name field represents the filename as it exists on the client
machine.
--->
<!--- I've added the CFMAIL below as debug, so far, no emails come through... --->
<cfmail from="err@lymlive.com.au" to="eliseo.dannunzio@lymlive.com.au" subject="Test" type="html">
foo bar
</cfmail>

<cfparam name="form.name" type="string" />

<!---
The File field represents the TMP file into which the binary
data of the upload is being stored. This can be accessed via
CFFile/Upload.
--->
<cfparam name="form.file" type="string" />


<!--- Sleep for a brief period to allow UI a chance to show. --->
<!--- ------------------------------------------------------ --->
<cfset sleep( 1000 ) />
<!--- ------------------------------------------------------ --->


<!--- Save the file to the uploads directory. --->
<cffile
result="upload"
action="upload"
filefield="file"
destination="#application.uploadsDirectory#"
nameconflict="makeunique"
/>

<!--- Return a success message. --->
<cfheader
statuscode="201"
statustext="Created"
/>
```

And the Application.cfc which channels the `application.uploadsDirectory` is below:

```
<cfscript>
component 
    output = "false"
    hint = "I define the application settings and event handlers."
    {
    // Define the application settings.
    this.name = hash( getCurrentTemplatePath() );
    this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan( 0, 0, 10, 0 );
    this.sessionManagement = false;
    // I initialize the application.
    function onApplicationStart(){
        // Get the root directory of the demo.
        var rootDirectory = getDirectoryFromPath( getCurrentTemplatePath() );
        // Set up the uploads directory.
        application.uploadsDirectory = (rootDirectory & "uploads/");
        // Return true so the application can load.
        return( true );
    }
    // I initialize the request.
    function onRequestStart(){
        // Check to see if we need to manually reset the application.
        if (structKeyExists( url, "init" )){
            this.onApplicationStart();
        }
        // Return true so the page can load.
        return( true );
    }
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Using cfmail isn't a particularly foolproof way of checking if a .cfm page is being executed, e.g. you may also have problems with your mailserver preventing emails being delivered.  What happens if you call upload_files.cfm directly, i.e. by submitting a normal form to it, not using plupload?

Comment: When you use your browser dev tools, what do you see in the Network panel?

Comment: @Duncan, I uncovered a few bugs with your suggestion... I'll throw an answer into the mix in a moment... Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ensured that I had a default file name set in the `form.name` `cfparam` tag in `uploadfiles.cfm` as well as re-writing the `Application.cfc` file as a standard `cfcomponent` version, instead of the `cfscript` version I had earlier...

It seems it was failing on the `output = false` statement in the `cfscript` tag... but I had no way of determining that from the plUpload routine...

Thanks for the heads up!